# Why is "each row and each column" followed by a singular verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, determiners, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

I am reading a book that contains the following text.

> A square matrix P is said to be a *permutation matrix* if each row and each column of P **contains** a single element 1, and the remaining elements are **zero**.

My questions are:

1. why is "contains" used? why not "contain"? Since there is a "and" before "contains".
2. why not "zeros" for the last word in the sentence?

Comment: Related: [Verbs after Compound Subjects (Everything… and Everyone…)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351494)

Comment: Also related: [Each apple and each orange {has/have}?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1472)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is a particular case of [compound subject](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_subject.htm), one or more nouns joined with a conjunction. When compound subjects are preceded by "each", "every", and certain other words, they are rendered singular, in an exception to the general rules. This explains the singular verb agreement in your example.

   So: "*the cup and bowl **contain** milk*", but
   "*each cup and each bowl **contains** milk*".

   [Your Dictionary](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/20-Rules-of-subject-verb-agreement.html)
   [University of West Florida](http://uwf.edu/writinglabapp/minilessons/mini-lesson_15x.htm)
   [Cuny School of Law](http://www.law.cuny.edu/legal-writing/students/grammar/subject-verb-agreement.html)
   [Southeastern Louisiana University](https://www.southeastern.edu/acad_research/programs/writing_center/handouts/pdf_handouts/subjectverbagreement.pdf)
2. Here, "zero" is used as an adjective, rather than as a plural noun. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zero):

   *a :  of, relating to, or being a zero*
   *b :  having no magnitude or quantity :  not any zero growth zero tolerance*

Comment: What are other words, besides each and every? Help!