# Subject-verb agreement dilemma

Tags: grammar

For the sentence mentioned below, which verb form (singular or plural) of "cost" fits correctly into the blank space and what is your reason for it:

"Every pale tomato slice, wilted pickle, and brown lettuce leaf [cost/costs] an extra 25 cents at Bernie's Burger Emporium."

I'm aware that "every" would take a singular verb in every case. However, does this still hold true when multiple entities are connected by the coordinating conjunction "and"?

Would your answer change if I write something like this:

"Every *item 1*, every *item 2*, and every *item 3* [cost/costs] an extra . . ."

Comment: See also [Why is “each row and each column” followed by a singular verb in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380700)

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.